# Issues with HUM on DIY audio signal switcher using a relay

Tags: audio, signal

I am creating a rack mounted system for toggling multiple guitar pedal effects remotely through a footswitch. The idea is that I create a signal chain starting with the output of a guitar and that going through a serial chain of eight relay boards and then into the amplifier. Each relay board will be able to add or remove an effect pedal from the signal chain, adding the effect or bypassing it. Something like a much simpler version of a device such as this one: https://www.boss.info/us/products/es-5/

I now have it built and mostly working except that I am getting a constant hum which sounds like some sort of a ground loop noise when I connect everything together. This is even happening if the device is not connected to power and I only connect the signal through the outer two connectors (see board below). I use a Panasonic TQ2-4.5 DPDT Relay for this.

Also I've uploaded the whole project schematics and designs on github and planning to document it much better when I get it working.

https://github.com/darko1002001/remote-guitar-pedal-controller

Here is the schematic of the relay circuit.

[image: How it looks]

[image: Schematic of relay circuit]

[image: Board layout of relay circuit]

Comment: If this the tip-ring-jack connector?

Comment: Yes, i added a photo of the build.

Comment: Bring any (plugged into the wall) power cord above the wiring. Listen to the hum; should get worse if the problem is ONLY Efield. If the hum gets worse only if the cord is carrying power, and the hum changes if you rotate the cord, the problem is mainly Hfield (magnetic field).

Comment: Does that top-left black wire actually make contact with the metal case? Did you strip away the black paint on the case? anodized cases may be a problem.

Comment: Yes, it does make contact. I will clean it up better. Thanks for the tip. Do you think it makes sense to try just a relay board outside of the enclosure to see if this problem happens? I tried just having it hang as far as possible and i still had the issue. Also the hum is much stronger if i connect the power adapter to the enclosure.

Comment: is the case STEEL or aluminum? 60Hz needs about 8 mm  (1/4")of aluminum for useful (only 9 dB, tho) magnetic shielding. Get some steel.

Comment: It is steel, the specification is 1.2mm steel case with 3mm aluminium front panel.

Comment: Stripping away the inner enclosure where the screw is mounted on the black wire did help significantly with the hum when the box is not connected to power. You cannot hear any noise now. But as soon as i connect it noise appears again.

Comment: Put on a steel bottom plate.

Answer (score 1):

You might have either 60Hz sinusoidal magnetic fields or electric fields intruding.

To reduce the magnetic field intrusion, add GND path immediately adjacent (or immediately under) the signal path. Or place a big piece of STEEL, that is grounded to your Ground wire, under the entire circuit.

To reduce the electric field intrusion, you need a big piece of metal that is grounded, under your signal path.

If Efield, simply wrapping your hands around the circuit will have an effect (good or bad).